# Rails 4.0 Collection Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, collections

I am very new to Rails 4.0 and having issues using the collection select in my form. I have an association where a Contract has many Task Orders. When creating a new Task Order I want the form to have a DDL of Contracts to select from.

My contracts table has the following attributes:
contractId
contractName

My task_orders table has the following attributes:
task_orderId
contract_Id <--- this is the foreign key reference to the contracts table

I read up on the Rails API and my for currently looks like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :contract_Id %><br>
  <%= collection.select(:TaskOrder, :contract_Id, :Contract.all, :id, {}, {}) %>
</div>
```

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :contract_Id %><br>
  <%= collection_select(:task_order,:contract_Id,Contract.all, :id, {}, {}) %>
</div>
```

You wrote **`:TaskOrder`** which is wrong.**`Model instance`** should be used as a `first param`,not the **`Class Name`** And also it is `collection_select` not `collection.select`

For more details,see this **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)**

**Update**

When using with `form helpers`,you should use `collection_select` like this

```
<%= f.collection_select(:contract_id,Contract.all, :id,:id,{:include_blank => true}) %>
```

Comment: also `Contract.all` instead of `:Contract.all`

Comment: Hi all - thanks for the help. @Pavan I tried that code but now i am getting the error:

undefined method `collection' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f993a4ad000>

Comment: use initial `f`,  `f.collection_select(:contract_id,Contract.all, :id, {}, {})`

Comment: `f.collection_select(:contract_id,Contract.all, :id, :id, {:include_blank => true})`